# Redoing a merge

Tags: git, github, merge

I'm having trouble reverting a failed merge. I have a branch, branch "B", which branches off branch A. A developer on my team recently merged their branch, branch "C" into "A".

On my local branch B, I pulled the most recent changes to make sure it was up to date, I then attempted to merge branch A into branch B. There were merge conflicts, which I attempted to resolve. I committed pushed the changes.

The build failed.

On my local copy of branch B, I did a git reset --hard  to bring me to the
second most recent commit (before the failed merge commit), which was the commit of the other developer merging their branch into branch A. I have no tried to redo the merge and merge branch A into branch B again. This time, my terminal says I am already up to date.

Can anybody explain this? Shouldn't I have merge conflicts I need to resolve again?

Comment: can you run `git log --oneline --graph` from branch B ? you should have a better view of your current state